# when i paint the texture the color likes Fragments

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

You see one on the right side. One brush one paint. But the color is like a fragment.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, that normals are inverted, and you're actually drawing on the opposite side of your mesh. Click on blackface culling option in shading settings:

[image]

This will hide parts of mesh that you can't draw because brush settings has this option enabled by default:

[image]

To fix normals, go to edit mode, select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: thank you very much!!!